# Why does turning debuggable off in android manifest cause data alignment error?

Tags: android, c++, native

I have been running and testing my android native app for weeks now in debug mode without issues. Today, I decided to test it in release mode by selecting "debuggable" as "false" in the android manifest and using ant release install to build.

However, when I attempt to run my app, I get an error message like:

I/DEBUG   (  264): signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1 (BUS_ADRALN), fault addr 5c27f389

which I assume is a data alignment error (according to google). But as soon as I turn debuggable on, the app no longer crashes.

What could've caused this error? I'm not even sure where to start to look because the crash only occurs when I turn debuggable off.

Answer (score 0):

SIGBUS is similar to SIGSEGV in that it is caused by an illegal memory access. When debugging is on, bigger blocks of memory are used making these problems less apparent. It does not mean the bug does not exist in the debug version, it just means it has not caused a crash. You might get a nasty memory corruption instead.

You are getting a crash so you are getting a crash dump. In the crash dump you will get a call-stack of addresses and .so files.

you can find the function that the addresses are using by calling addr2line with the address and the module. If you want a full dissassembly objdump can be used. You will either have to install the arm versions of these programs or use the ones that come in the android NDK.